# Intellij highlights error but code can be compiled and running correctly

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I met a strange issue in Intellij Ultimate 2019.3.2.  It indicates a Java generic type error, like 'reason: no instance(s) of type variable(s) exist so that OCPerson conforms to IBaseObject' when I integrated a jar which provides a generic method in my current project, but the project can be compiled without any error or warning in Oracle JDK 8. More strange, when I use the generic method as source code directly, Intellij doesn't promote the error any more. Please see the detailed information in below:

The generic method signature looks like the below:

```
public static <T extends IBaseObject> void setEntityNameForMapObject(Map map, String key, Class<T> entityClass)
```

I built it  as a single jar library. When I used this jar in a project, Intellij indicated the below error information. Actually, Gradle can compile the project correctly and there is no any warning message. BTW, the Intellij  uses JDK 1.8.0_152. When I copy the source code in the current project, the indicated error message is gone in Intellij. 
[image: Please see the error snapshot]

Comment: Can you show us the code, where IntelliJ marks the error?

Comment: File -> Invalidate caches and restart

Comment: The problem still exists even I did specify the latest IDEA JDK and "Invalidate caches and restart".